# Rank all columns in a table/view

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there an efficient way to Rank all columns in a table/view. I have a `sqlite3` database of a hockey team statistics from various years. The main application calls on the database and will query based on a particular season. In certain cases I need to rank this data so the user can compare teams.

I am well aware of the `RANK()` function provided in sqlite3 version >3.25. My current solution simply involves creating a query on a view of:

```sql
SELECT wins, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY wins DESC) AS wins_rank, ... 20 more columns
FROM table;
```

Is there a better way to structure the query other than typing out the `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col) AS col_rank` for each column?

It should also be noted that as a season progresses the stat ranks will change, so I decided against creating individual "rank" columns in the table.

Comment: There is not an "easier way".  You can use a spreadsheet to generate the code.

Answer (score 0):

The better thing to do is to change your data structure.  You can store the data with one row per "value", say:

- `team_id`
- `statistic`
- `value`

Then you can use:

```
select team_id, statistics,
       rank() over (partition by team_id, statistic order by value desc) as ranking
from team_statistics;
```

Of course, the results will then be in separate rows.  To get them in one row, you would need to pivot the data -- and that would require a longish query.